Use a SBT task with different settings from one module
When testing locally, I do not care about code size, therefore I switch GCC off by using following line in my frontend and worker modules settings:
Compile / fullLinkJS / scalaJSLinkerConfig ~= { _.withOptimizer(true).withClosureCompiler(false) },

The only situation where I want to use the closure compiler is when producing JS files for the backend to be published. This is done like this:
  Compile / resourceGenerators += Def.task {
    Seq(
      (frontend / Compile / fullOptJS).value.data,
      (worker / Compile / fullOptJS).value.data
    )
  }.taskValue,

Currently I do this manually in my SBT - during development I add this line and remove or disable it when publishing. Is there some way to have this more principled and automatic?
Can I have different settings for frontend / fullOptJS when not used standalone and from backend resourceGenerators? Or can I define a new custom task fullOptJSLocal which will set the required settings and do what fullOptJS would do with those settings? I can define a new task, but I did not found how to change the settings:
// Define a new task for fullOptJS which is optimized but fast (no minimizer, no Closure Compiler)
lazy val fullOptJSLocal = taskKey[Attributed[File]]("fullOptJSLocal")

fullOptJSLocal := {
  val prev = (Compile / fullOptJS).value
  val newConfig = (Compile / fullLinkJS / scalaJSLinkerConfig).value.withClosureCompiler(false)
  /// now what ???
  prev
}


Please pardon the obvious question but... why not use fastOptJS then? The distincition between fastOptJS and fullOptJS is precisely to fulfill the use case of testing versus production deployment.

Because I have fastOptJS configured with optimizations disabled for easier debugging. Sometimes when I want to test something on a larger scale I want to run optimized build, as it is substantially faster. The optimization itself is reasonably fast, but Closure takes "Oh So Long".
